# Converting long string of comma delimited integers into x and y columns

Tags: r, stata, data-manipulation

My data is a long, single line of values separated by commas where every other value is an x or a y coordinate

Data looks like this:
2622731,1387660,2621628,1444522,2619235,1681640

But I want it to look like this:

2622731,1387660

2621628,1444522

2619235,1681640

Short of going through the entire file and deleting the comma and hitting enter as I did for the example above, how might I automate this in R (or  Stata)?

Comment: another way is : `read.csv(text=gsub("(,\\d+),","\\1\n",data), header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R:

```
## Read in your data
## data = readLines("path/to/your_file.txt")
## Should get you something like this (using the example in your Q)
data = "2622731,1387660,2621628,1444522,2619235,1681640"
data = unlist(strsplit(data, ","))
data = matrix(as.numeric(data), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
data
#         [,1]    [,2]
# [1,] 2622731 1387660
# [2,] 2621628 1444522
# [3,] 2619235 1681640
```

At that point, perhaps

```
data = as.data.frame(data)
names(data) = c("x", "y")
#         x       y
# 1 2622731 1387660
# 2 2621628 1444522
# 3 2619235 1681640
```

Comment: Thank you a billion!! I had to change to (strsplit(as.character(x),",")) but finally got it!

Answer (score 1):

In Stata the analogue of the accepted R solution might involve `split` and `reshape long`. Here is another approach:

```
* data example 
clear
set obs 1
gen strL data = "2622731,1387660,2621628,1444522,2619235,1681640"

* code for data example 
replace data = subinstr(data, ",", " ", .)
set obs `=wordcount(data)/2' 
gen x = real(word(data[1], 2 * _n - 1))
gen y = real(word(data[1], 2 * _n))

list 

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                                            data         x         y |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2622731 1387660 2621628 1444522 2619235 1681640   2622731   1387660 |
  2. |                                                   2621628   1444522 |
  3. |                                                   2619235   1681640 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scan` and reshape with `matrix`:

```
s <- "2622731,1387660,2621628,1444522,2619235,1681640" # test data

matrix(scan(text = s, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
##         [,1]    [,2]
## [1,] 2622731 1387660
## [2,] 2621628 1444522
## [3,] 2619235 1681640
```